# populate input field using AppleScript and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, input, applescript, field

I've searched stack overflow but the provided solutions did not work, so I am posting this question:

I've got the following HTML Element:

```
<input xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="loginform:fPers" type="text" name="loginform:fPers" value class="inputFieldApp" maxlength="20" tabindex="4" title="Some title">
```

This is an existing HTML element from a website that I want to fill in using JavaScript.

I am using AppleScript to script this. 
The script just opens Chrome but does nothing:
It should click on a button and populate an input field.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate

    set thescript to "document.getElementById(\"loginform:kommenbtn\").click();"

    set thescript2 to "document.getElementById(\"loginform:fPers\").value = \"112233\";"
    execute javascript thescript2
end tell
```

I tried this on www.google.de to see if the problem was site-specific, but it does not work either. I want to fetch the country data on that site. It has the following class:

```
<span class="_Vbu">​Deutschland​</span>​
```

I tried to call it by classname:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    set thescript to "document.getElementByClassName('_Vbu').innerHTML"
    set myvar to execute active tab of front window javascript thescript
    display dialog myvar
end tell
```

I always get the following display dialog content: msng

Comment: What's the actual URL of the web page? BTW You need to tell Google Chrome where to execute the JavaScript, e.g,  `execute active tab of front window javascript ...`

Comment: I used `active tab of front window...` but that still does not work. It does not work on any website. I updated the question to reflect all of this.

Comment: You get `msng ` in the `display dialog` because what's returned is `missing value`. I couldn't find `<span class="_Vbu">​Deutschland​</span>​` on www.google.de. That said, you may have to use the following form when using `getElementsByClassName`, e.g: `"document.getElementsByClassName('className')[0].innerHTML;"` BTW `className` has to be a valid class name _value_ for it to return other then `missing value` when the  _value_ is actually something.

Comment: `[0]` did the trick...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted on the comments, `[0]` did the trick.

The classname was right as you can see in the following screenshot:
[image: www.google.de]

This is how it works using Google Chrome:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    set thescript to "document.getElementsByClassName('_Vbu')[0].innerHTML;"
    set myvar to execute active tab of front window javascript thescript
    display dialog myvar
end tell
```

This is how it works using Safari:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set thescript to "document.getElementsByClassName('_Vbu')[0].innerHTML;"
    tell document 1
        set myvar to do JavaScript thescript
    end tell
    display dialog myvar
end tell
```

If you get the error "myvar is not declared" make sure you address the right document in AppleScript.

It got me the right text in the display dialog ("Deutschland") both times.